# Change colors that do not match specific color(s) to white using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to grab specific elements out of the image. So far what I have done is reduced the number of colors in the image, and gotten a dictionary of colors with their counts. What I want to do now is replace all colors which do not match this specific color to white, so that I can iterate over the image and create different images where each image only has one object of that particular color.

This is what I've done so far:

```
def showOnlyOneColor(img, rgb_key):
    print("Getting only one color")
    rgb_key = rgb_key.split("-")
    r = int(rgb_key[0])
    g = int(rgb_key[1])
    b = int(rgb_key[2])

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    rgb_low = np.array([r,g,b])
    rgb_high = np.array([r,g,b])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, rgb_low, rgb_high)
    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, contours, (255, 255, 255))
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)


    return result
```

Second attempt:

```
def showOnlyOneColor(img, rgb_key):
    print("Getting only one color")
    rgb_key = rgb_key.split("-")
    r = int(rgb_key[0])
    g = int(rgb_key[1])
    b = int(rgb_key[2])

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    rgb_low = np.array([r,g,b])
    rgb_high = np.array([r,g,b])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, rgb_low, rgb_high)

    img[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)

    return img
```

This results in a white image for all iterations

This is what I'm using to reduce the number of colors in the image:

```
def reduceNumberOfColors(img):
    div = 128
    return img // div * div + div // 2
```

Latest attempt:

```
def showOnlyOneColor(img, rgb_key):
    print("Getting only one color")
    rgb_key = rgb_key.split("-")
    r = int(rgb_key[0])
    g = int(rgb_key[1])
    b = int(rgb_key[2])
    hsv_color = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    rgb_low = np.array(hsv_color)
    rgb_high = np.array(hsv_color)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, rgb_low, rgb_high)

    img[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)

    return img
```

One of the resulting images shows something, the rest of the images are white

How I organize rgb:

```
def getColorCount(img):
    color_dict = {}
    print("Getting color count")
    for i in tqdm(range(img.shape[0])):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            color = img[i,j]
            r = color[0]
            g = color[1]
            b = color[2]
            rgb_askey = str(r)+"-"+str(g)+"-"+str(b)
            if rgb_askey not in color_dict.keys():
                color_dict[rgb_askey] = 1
            else:
                color_dict[rgb_askey] += 1
    return color_dict
```

Comment: Threshold the image for the desired good color that you want to keep. Then use the mask to change all other pixels to white.  Given your input image as `image` and the mask as `mask`, do the following: `image[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)`

Comment: @fmw42 If I implement the mask as you just specified, I just get a white image

Comment: What does your mask look like? Does it show some white and some black?  Is your mask 1 channel or 3 channels? If 3 channels, make it 1 channel.

Comment: Please show your input image

Comment: Why are you converting to HSV, but using RGB values?

Comment: [Here is the image I'm trying to process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek1Dx.jpg) My mask is defined in the code above

Comment: Is the mask all white? Why are you converting to HSV but using RGB values and also OpenCV uses BGR values. So your inRange() values may not be correct. What part are you trying to isolate by your threshold?

Comment: @fmw42 I didn't know I needed to convert rgb to HSV. So is that the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to isolate all parts of the image which are generally a different color from the rest

Comment: No HSV is fine. But you cannot give it RGB values. You must give it HSV values. So perhaps you should just inRange() on BGR values (not RGB values)

Comment: @fmw42 Can you provide example code? I'm confused, sorry.

Comment: Where do your RGB values come from? Are you using some kind of color picker?

Comment: @fmw42 I'm reducing the number of colors in the image and then iterating over the colors which are left. I'm processing the image which had the colors reduced

Comment: @fmw42 I included the function that I used to reduce the number of colors in my latest edit

Comment: How are you reducing colors? Are you using OpenCV kmeans to do that? If so the colors are BGR unless you changed your input to RGB

Comment: I'm updating the code to show you what I did now

Comment: How are you getting each color from the reduced image?

Comment: @fmw42 I iterate over the shape (width/height) of the image and reference the pixel by image[i,j]. If the pixel has been encountered before I increase the count in a dictionary that holds the color values by r-g-b as keys and their frequencies as the values

Comment: Colors in OpenCV are b, g, r not r, g, b. Please show code the gets the color of a pixel and puts that color into your R, G, B values.

Comment: I am trying to understand whether you are properly converting to R,G,B or you have B,G,R values in R,G,B names

Comment: @fmw42 I've added the code which shows how I arrange the colors. It's RGB not BGR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want in Python/OpenCV. Note colors are in the order B,G,R.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('corn.jpg')

# do simple color reduction
imgcopy = img.copy()
div = 128
imgcopy = div * ( imgcopy // div ) + div // 2

# get list of unique colors
list_bgr_colors = np.unique(imgcopy.reshape(-1, imgcopy.shape[2]), axis=0)
print(list_bgr_colors)
print(list_bgr_colors[1])

# save reduced color image
cv2.imwrite("corn_reduced_colors.png", imgcopy)

# display reduced color image
cv2.imshow("reduced_colors", imgcopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)   

# loop over colors in list and change all non-specified colors to white
i = 1
for color in list_bgr_colors:

    # threshold on the specified color
    lower=np.array((color))
    upper=np.array((color))
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgcopy, lower, upper)

    # change all non-specified color to white
    result = imgcopy.copy()
    result[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)

    # save results
    cv2.imwrite("corn_color_{0}.png".format(i), result)

    # display result
    cv2.imshow("result", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    # increment
    i += 1
```

List of Reduced Colors:

```
[[ 64  64  64]
 [ 64  64 192]
 [ 64 192  64]
 [ 64 192 192]
 [192 192 192]]
```

Reduced Color Image:

[image]

Individual Color Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV. Note that OpenCV colors are in the order B,G,R.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('corn.jpg')

# threshold on yellow color
lower=(0,170,215)
upper=(70,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# change all non-yellow to white
result = img.copy()
result[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('corn_yellow.jpg',result)

# display result
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Colors in OpenCV are in the order B,G,R.

So try this in Python/OpenCV.

```
def showOnlyOneColor(img, bgr_key):
    print("Getting only one color")
    bgr_key = bgr_key.split("-")
    b = int(bgr_key[0])
    g = int(bgr_key[1])
    r = int(bgr_key[2])
    bgr_low = np.array((b,g,r))
    bgr_high = np.array((b,g,r))
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, bgr_low, bgr_high)

    img[mask!=255] = (255, 255, 255)

    return img
```

**ADDITION**

I think your issue is in your assumption that you have RGB colors when you use colorsys to convert from RGB to HSV.  Your colors are actually B, G, R. So to use colorsys you need to convert your image to RGB first or better reverse the order of the colors that you extract from B,G,R to R,G,B before using colorsys.

Your dictionary colors are actually B, G, R not R, G, B. So reverse them or reverse them later when using colorsys.

Comment: So the first image is not all white, it shows the objects in the white image as gray. But then for every other color the image is entirely white. Also bgr_low and bgr_high have typos. They need to be np.array((b,g,r))

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typos. Please see my addition in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but my image is still not filtering out objects according to color. The first image (the first color it finds) shows a white image with gray objects in it, but the rest of the images are just entirely white.

Comment: Post your reduced color image. Do the colors look proper?

Comment: [So it turns out that I will have to change the amount that I scale the colors down relative to the number of colors](https://i.imgur.com/WIBDB7a.jpg)

Comment: This should still result in two images with two separate colors

Comment: You should copy the input and process the copy at the end so that you do not write over the same image each time.